# Transfer Image from a harware module to an Android phone over WiFi

Tags: android, image, wifi

Well can anyone suggest me if i can transfer image from a Hardware module lets say a microscope which has WIFI capability.

Can anyone  give any one give any some pointers how to go about this application how to receive an image over WiFI  which directly gets transported to my Android app.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a server, maybe written by java, which will handle the data between APP and server. This server can also communicate with your hardware, as you said, the microscope. You can find the command set to build this connection between microscope and server. For example, you use the server send a command: "reset", it will be reset. If you send command "take a photo", it will take a photo.  So you need to send varieties commands to control it. Finally, the server will handle these datas among of APP, Server and hardware. As your question didn't mention what specify device, this is just a big graph to describe it.

Good luck on it.